# Como manipular informações específicas de um arquivo TXT no C++?

Tags: c++, txt

O arquivo .txt contém as seguintes linhas:
1.55  66.5
1.80  90.2
1.66  65.1
1.70  70.0
1.65  58.8
1.58  53.5
1.72  68.5
1.63  67.9
1.71  69.4
1.67  62.4

Preciso fazer a média da altura, média do peso e mostrar na tela o maior peso e a maior altura. São 10 linhas contendo 10 caracteres em cada linha. A primeira coluna é a altura e a segunda o peso.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream arquivo;
    string sNomArq,sLinha;
    int iQtdLinhas = 0;
    float fAlt,fPes,fAltMed,fPesMed,fSomAlt,fSomPes;
    sNomArq = "grupo.txt";
    arquivo.open(sNomArq);
    if (arquivo.is_open()){
        while (!arquivo.eof()){
            getline(arquivo,sLinha);

            /* Estou travando na parte de ler o espaço específico da altura/peso em cada linha e 
               manipular esses dados em formato float */
           
            fSomAlt = fSomAlt + fAlt;
            fSomPes = fSomPes + fPes;
            iQtdLinhas++;
        }
        fAltMed = fSomAlt / iQtdLinhas;
        cout << "ALTURA MEDIA = " << fAltMed << endl;
        fPesMed = fSomPes / iQtdLinhas;
        cout << "PESO MEDIO = " << fPesMed << endl;
        fPesMed = 0;
        cout << "MAIOR ALTURA = " << fPesMed << endl;
        fPesMed = 0;
        cout << "MAIOR PESO = " << fPesMed << endl;
    }else{
        cout << "Arquivo nao encontrado" << endl;
    }
    arquivo.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Faltou inicializar as variáveis acumuladoras `fSomAlt` e `fSomPes` com 0. Você está lendo uma linha inteira, então precisa pegar as duas variáveis da string lida (pode utilizar a função stof). Caso tenha ocorrido algum outro erro favor relata-lo.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Já implementei. Tem alguma ideia de como proceder para armazenar os caracteres da altura e do peso em variáveis distintas `sAlt` e `sPes` ? E como comparar a nova variável float (conversão da string) para ver qual o maior valor?

Comment: Por qual motivo você não utiliza o cin para ler diretamente as duas variáveis `fAlt` e `fPes` ao invés de ler a linha inteira e depois separar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream arquivo;
    string sLinha,sAlt,sPes;
    int iQtdLinhas=0;
    float fAlt,fPes,fAltMed,fPesMed,fSomAlt=0,fSomPes=0,fMaxAlt=0,fMaxPes=0;
    arquivo.open("grupo.txt");
    if (arquivo.is_open()){
        while (!arquivo.eof()){
            getline(arquivo,sLinha);
            sAlt = sLinha.substr(0,4);
            sPes = sLinha.substr(6,4);
            fAlt = stof(sAlt);
            fPes = stof(sPes);
            fSomAlt = fSomAlt + fAlt;
            fSomPes = fSomPes + fPes;
            if (fMaxAlt < fAlt){
                fMaxAlt = fAlt;
            }
            if (fMaxPes < fPes){
                fMaxPes = fPes;
            }
            iQtdLinhas++;
        }
        fAltMed = fSomAlt / iQtdLinhas;
        cout << "ALTURA MEDIA = " << fAltMed << endl;
        fPesMed = fSomPes / iQtdLinhas;
        cout << "PESO MEDIO = " << fPesMed << endl;
        cout << "MAIOR ALTURA = " << fMaxAlt << endl;
        cout << "MAIOR PESO = " << fMaxPes << endl;
    }else{
        cout << "Arquivo nao encontrado" << endl;
    }
    arquivo.close();
    return 0;
}
```